# How can I use a variable inside a SELECT statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I am a newbie to SQL. The problem which I am facing is, I want to select a particular name **John** from the customer table, but I am storing  John in a string called `var_name`. Now is there any way that I can use this variable name in the select statement instead of writing John?

sorry i forgot to explain the question in depth,

i am having a table which contains details of the customers, among that customer name is one of the coloumn, so when user clicks on any particular name from customer name coloumn that name is getting stored in the variable called var_name and i want that particular customer name's customer id, this is the issue which i didnt mention in the question above. So i want that random value clicked in the coloumn should get replace in the SELECT statement. your query will work if the user clicks on John, i want a general query for the above issue

Here is an example

```
SELECT var_name -- this is what I've used, is there any other way to accomplish this?
FROM Customer
Where Customer_ID = '1234';
```

so please help me out to solve this issue.

Thank You!

Comment: Which RDBMS? Explain better your final goal please.

Comment: Please add the variable definition, plus the RDBMS you're using.

Comment: i am using SQL server Management studio.

Comment: You said you are storing customer name into string called var_name. So you want the customer name in code behind ? If so, what kind of language you are using ?

Comment: I am using c# to grab the particular username which user clicks and store it back in variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you are using SQL server,
You can actually declare your var_name:

`DECLARE @var_name nvarchar(50)
SET @var_name = (SELECT "something" FROM Customer WHERE Customer_ID = '1234')`
`from here, you can do whatever you want with @var_name`

Comment: This will only work for SQL server, whereas the OP hasn't yet stated which RDBMS they're using.

Comment: @FrankSchmitt Yes, i amended it in my answer. Thanks

Comment: Thank you,  with slight altration this query worked for me, thanks a ton Jacky! have a nice day ahead :)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap a single-value select in brackets to use its value in another query:

```
select something
from sometable
where somecolumn = (SELECT name FROM Customer Where Customer_ID = '1234')
```

Comment: @KarthikPB Please don't add additional info in comments. Edit your question instead (there's a nice button called **edit** for that :-) )

Comment: Done with it Frank :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is the what you are asking for,

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Your connection goes here");
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select name from customer where customerid = '1234'",con);
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while(dr.Read())
{
  string var_name = dr.GetString(0);
}
con.Close();
```

This is one of the way that you can the store the values from database to your string.